# Will Windows 7 factory reset remove all my private data?

Tags: windows-7, windows, privacy, reset, factory-defaults

EDIT: this is NOT a duplicate of [How to factory restore Windows 7 to prepare to sell laptop](https://superuser.com/questions/282320/how-to-factory-restore-windows-7-to-prepare-to-sell-laptop?lq=1).  That question is about someone who's computer came with XP, mine came with Windows 7.

I intend to sell an old laptop that came with Windows 7 installed.  I don't have install disks.

If I follow the instructions here (for a factory reset):
http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN291879/EN

Will this be sufficient to guarantee nobody can access any private data I have on the machine?

And will I have to worry about DRM stuff at all?  They mention it here: http://www.howtogeek.com/171980/how-to-prepare-a-computer-tablet-or-phone-before-selling-it/

If it *is* more complicated than just following the steps in the first link, what else do I need to do?

Comment: Right on the page you linked: "Warning: Restoring your computer to the factory settings will remove all files and programs except those it came with. **You will lose all personal files, including photos, emails and programs, if you do not back up your files and data**".  Really, the best bet it to nuke the whole drive (including the recovery partition) and reinstall Windows from disk or if you trust it, use a free-space shredding program (both covered in the duplicate).

Comment: I know it says that.  But I'm not sure if I can trust it.  And then you say the best bet is something else (if I understand correctly).  As I mention, I don't have the install disk(s).  What do you mean "both covered in the duplicate"?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate because in the other question, the user's machine came with XP, and they upgraded to Windows 7 with a disk.

Comment: In fact, rereading it, they also say: "If your laptop or desktop computer has a traditional magnetic hard drive, it’s possible for people to recover the data from the hard drive even after you reformat it and reinstall the operating system. This is because reinstalling the operating system won’t erase every sector of the disk."

So... it seems like a Catch-22.